# Fb.Login() does not popup OAuth Dialog?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I'm study fb api recently

and I use fb api to do login,

however, when I use Fb.Login() method, and scope the permission that I needed.

I found the problem that when I use account ( this account is also the fb app admin )

to login, everything is be work including login dialog and oauth dialog ,

but when I use another account ( General account )

the login dialog is work but OAuth Dialog is not work .

I've tried another account ( General account ), it had the same situation,

Only when I use the account which is also the fb app owner account would be work.

Any Ideas ?

Below is the code...

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        alert('success !') ;
    } else {
        alert(' faild ! ');
    }
}, { scope: "publish_actions" });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Login does not popup oauth dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422936/facebook-login-does-not-popup-oauth-dialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem a while back.

Be sure to check that your app is not in [Development mode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity#sandbox). When you're in Development mode your app is hidden from anybody who hasn't been authorized in the App Dashboard.

If you are in Development mode and don't want to unleash your awesome Facebook application to the web just yet, I'd recommend opening up your App Dashboard, clicking Roles, and creating a Test User. After you've done that you'll be presented with a table of Test Users. Click the 'Edit' icon (looks like a pencil) and give the Test User a password.

Good stuff.

Next step is to head back over to your Facebook application, and fire your login code.

When the Login Dialog box appears, type in your new Test User's details and it should work just fine.

Comment: Another Question below plz figure it out for me thanks u

Comment: @cnz81 have you checked to see if your email is set in the Settings panel? Other than that my bet would be that you need to put your app on a domain with an SSL certificate. You'll then need need to update your app settings. Make sure it's a signed SSL certificate that way the browser won't throw errors.

Comment: William Minty, I capture my screen and upload at the follow url.

Comment: William Minty, Plz Help me.
I'm very sure that my apps is not in the development Mode.
is there any other solutions ? http://imgur.com/foy277W

Comment: @cnz81 Hey man. You're definitely not in development mode. Just to clarify, you're logging in with an account that is NOT an admin or developer account, correct? Do you have the app hosted somewhere online where I could test it? It might be a bit quicker.

Comment: Also you're using publish_actions. That permission requires review from Facebook. That could be the problem.

Comment: That Right! I'm using publish_actions. so the permission isn't free now ?

Comment: @cnz81 Nah I think you'll find it's an extended permission. Bit of a pain.

Comment: Yap. I know that is an extended permission. So what should I do to Deal with it ?

Comment: @cnz81 You need to submit your app for review in your App Dashboard. If you can, I'd avoid submission until you've completed your app. I've read that the review can take up to a week :p