# Facebook Login does not popup oauth dialog?

Tags: facebook, authentication, popup, oauth-2.0

I'm very sure that my app is not in Development Mode !

but the problem is still occur.

Has any good idea ?

below is the setting of my fb app.

[image: http://imgur.com/foy277W]

when I use Fb.Login() method, and scope the permission that I needed.

I found the problem that when I use account ( this account is also the fb app admin )

to login, everything is be work including login dialog and oauth dialog ,

but when I use another account ( General account )

the login dialog is work but OAuth Dialog is not work .

I've tried another account ( General account ), it had the same situation,

Only when I use the account which is also the fb app owner account would be work.

Any Ideas ?

Below is the code...

```
FB.login(function (response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
    alert('success !') ;
} else {
    alert(' faild ! ');
}
}, { scope: "publish_actions" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because your App is not on a real server but on "localhost". Try uploading it to a real server (with a public domain) and add the domain to the "App Domains" field too.

Also, keep in mind that `publish_actions` will only work for Users with a role in the App Settings. For other Users, you need to go through a review process now: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Basic login should still work without approval, but `publish_actions` will not be included without review.